# Installing Node Modules in a Standalone Environment

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, manual

I'm working with NodeJS in a small standalone isolated environment, as such commands like `npm install -g` can't reach out to the internet for dependencies. To "workaround" this constraint, I'm doing installs on a regular system and just air-gaping the pieces over.

Any given module (and all its dependencies) lives in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/XXXXX, and if I'm actually in that directory and enter `node cli.js`, it works.

However, back on the main system invoking module XXXXX by name from the command line runs that particular module. The isolated system does not, and I'm trying to find that last little step of how *npm* is wiring things up.

What's the *pedantic* methodology once one's this far to teach npm (or node) of the new command?
I'm willing to resort to hacks or aliases if absolutely necessary, but I'd like to do it the npm way.

Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to set up a CouchDB or such and run a mirrored repository — I'm working in a tight footprint that's trying to keep things small and sleek.

Comment: The `npm` command need not to install from the Internet only. You can do `npm install <tarball file>`. So, you could tar all your dependencies into a tarball file and then install them this way.

Comment: I assume that tarball would have to be organized in some particular manner. Some of the packages I'm trying to install contain 50+ other packages, which very well could contain their own dependencies. At the moment it seems air-lifting /usr/local/lib/node_modules from one machine to another gets everything, but it's that last step to make the system aware that node is implied that's not working for me.